# Disable submit button until recaptcha3 g-recaptcha-response value is retrived

Tags: javascript, laravel

nowadays SEO has a major impact on site load speed and when I add google recaptcha3 it reduces my site speed to 35-40% in google lighthouse results that why I decided to load recaptcha3 lib only when user click or fill the form field. I had written this code and it is working fine for me.

---

**Html form field**

```
  <div class="control is-loading">
      <input name="instauser" id="author" class="input is-rounded is-focused is-medium" type="text" placeholder="https://instagram.com/p/41SW_pmmq4/">
   </div>
   <input type="hidden" id="g-recaptcha-response" name="g-recaptcha-response" value="">
   <div class="control has-text-centered"><br>
      <button id="Button" type="submit" class="button is-danger is-active is-medium">Download &nbsp
      <img src="{{ asset('svg/downloads.svg') }}" width="25px"
         alt="Instagram video download" />
      </button>
   </div>
</form>
```

**javascript code**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var reCaptchaFocus = function() {
var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=6LdvEswUAAAAADNVG2ng4ZIfA4mfKUJiuLmLgnUy';
head.appendChild(script);

var recaptchaInterval = setInterval(function() {
if( !window.grecaptcha || !window.grecaptcha.execute ) { return; }

clearInterval( recaptchaInterval );

grecaptcha.execute('6LdvEswUAAAAADNVG2ng4ZIfA4mfKUJiuLmLgnUy', {action: 'homepage'}).then(function(token) {
document.getElementById('g-recaptcha-response').value=token;
});
}, 100 );
    document.getElementById('author').removeEventListener('focus', reCaptchaFocus);
    };
    document.getElementById('author').addEventListener('focus', reCaptchaFocus, false);
</script>
```

but now the problem is that when the user internet is slow then it takes time in loading the hidden g-recaptcha-response input value and due to this sometimes user submit the form before loading of the hidden g-recaptcha-response value. thats why i want to disable the submit button until the g-recaptcha-response value is filled in hidden input type to avoid any error..... hero is the website to test https://igsavers.com

need some help

Answer (score -1, accepted):

here is the answer to my question

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var reCaptchaFocus = function() {
var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=6LdvEswUAAAAADNVG2ng4ZIfA4mfKUJiuLmLgnUy';
head.appendChild(script);
document.getElementById("Button").disabled = true;

var recaptchaInterval = setInterval(function() {
if( !window.grecaptcha || !window.grecaptcha.execute ) { return; }

clearInterval( recaptchaInterval );

grecaptcha.execute('6LdvEswUAAAAADNVG2ng4ZIfA4mfKUJiuLmLgnUy', {action: 'homepage'}).then(function(token) {
document.getElementById('g-recaptcha-response').value=token;
document.getElementById("Button").disabled = false;
//document.querySelector('button[type="submit"]').setAttribute('disabled', '');
});
}, 100 );
    document.getElementById('author').removeEventListener('focus', reCaptchaFocus);
    };
    document.getElementById('author').addEventListener('focus', reCaptchaFocus, false);
</script>
```